Why is my pc blank once logged in
I’m not sure if this has been answered or not but when I open my pc, the sign in screen is grey with no background. I then login and my desktop is completely blank. No files, no games, no task bar, and the windows button doesn’t work. I’ve tried task manager but it won’t open. I’ve tried to turn it off and on again, and it does the same thing. I’ve tried control+alt+delete and nothing happens.
Before this happening, my game said it was still running when I closed it, and since task manager doesn’t work, I just closed the pc. When reopening it, this problem occurred.
Is there anything I can do on my own or would I have to give my pc to a professional to fix it?
Thanks :)

Try Win+R, then inputting explorer.exe and hittingEnter?


First step, see if there is hardware damage, such as to an SSD.

Create a bootable USB, such as Ubuntu Live, Hiren’s BootCD PE, etc.
Open BIOS/UEFI configuration to allow booting from USB, and save settings.
Boot from USB (do not install anything on the main drive).
Open a file manager, such as Windows Explorer or Ubuntu Files, and check the main drive to see if partitions are OK.
You might want to use one of the tools on those bootable USB drives to make a disk image, to avoid further los of data.


If the drive is basically working, download the Windows 10 ISO and create a bootable installation disk, then reinstall Windows 10, keeping files.
If the drive is badly damaged, you might try to recover files, or get help from a professional.

